# Global Wordpress IMG directory function

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using Bones theme to develop wordpress themes. Images are stored in **'theme/lib/images/site/'**. To load an image in a template I a currently using:

```
<?php get_template_directory_uri().'/library/images/'; ?>
```

I would like to add this directory as a global variable in functions.php so I can use a shortcode to load images, for example.

```
<?php echo imgDir(); ?>
```

My first thought would be to use something like

```
function imgDir() {
     $path_to_image = get_template_directory_uri() . '/library/images/';
}
```

But does not seem to be working, am I missing something simple here? Shouldn't be to hard to add a short code like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return your value:

```
function imgDir() {
    return get_template_directory_uri() . '/library/images/';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to add a shortcode hook according to the [Wordpress Documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode) is this.

Inside your **functions.php**

```
function imgDir( $atts ){
    return get_template_directory_uri() . '/library/images/';
}
add_shortcode( 'imgdir', 'imgDir' );
```

So the shortcode `[imgdir]` will return the desired path.

To call a shortcode inside your PHP-File just use the `do_shortcode()` function like this -

`echo do_shortcode('[imgdir]');` ([Documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/))

Comment: How is this better than using the function method? With this i would use <?php echo imgDir() ?>

Comment: Well, it's not better on functional basis (except that you could use the shortcode `[imgdir]` inside your editor in backend). It's just the proper way according to the documentation, code styling / readability.

Comment: As I will only be using within templates it would not hurt to use a function rather than shortcode right? I do try to keep to docs as much as possible but seems function method is tidier

Comment: Sure, it's up to you. :)

Comment: Cool, thanks for info about shortcodes though, sure it will come in handy in the future!